# AWS SDK CPP: Download directory (key prefix) recursively without pre-known number of files

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-cpp

I am using the AWS-CPP-SDK TransferManager for downloading files and folders(recursively) from S3 bucket. In this [example code](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-cpp/blob/master/aws-cpp-sdk-transfer-tests/TransferTests.cpp#L599) the transfer handler triggers `directoryDownloadSignal.notify_one()` after 3 file downloads have started.

I am looking to recursively download from a folder without number of files known previously. How can I replace the `if (directoryUploads.size() == 3)` statement appropriately ?

Comment: Please check your hyperlink to the "example code."  It  looks like you may have linked to a local file.  It's not a working link.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot fixed it. Thanks :)

Comment: Currently, You don't know when it's going to finish because neither you nor the SDK know how many files remain to be downloaded. But we can implement a new way to notify users when it's done with downloading. We'll do that soon.

Comment: @user2706071 yes that would be great. The Java and Python SDKs provide ways to do so. Implementing in C++ would be really great.